# the port_no in struct vport of openvswitch is different from the port number?

Tags: virtualization, sdn, openvswitch

I modified the ovs2.6.0 and want to handle some packets. 
I printk the prev_port(prev_port = nla_get_u32(a)) in do_execute_actions function. However, the prev_port sometimes is not the correct port number which the packet is forwarded to. But the TCP transmission is normal. I guess that the port number in ovs is numbered in a random way?

Comment: What do you mean by "But the TCP transmission is normal"? In your flow table, do you send packets to a single port? Could it be that you are actually looking for the `vport`: https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/b0a47d0d404fd021eac3bf4e0c3c349f5eca250d/datapath/actions.c#L759

Comment: yes, it is the vport you mentioned. for example, I create a simple topology in Mininet: there is only one switch named s1.(h1-eth0<->s1-eth1,h2-eth0<->s1-eth2,h3-eth0<->s1-eth3). And I printk the outport number of packet SYN, when h1 send TCP packets to h2 and h3. The outport numbers is not the same as the ones that are described in my topology.But the TCP transmission can be done normally.

Comment: Do the port numbers match the ofport values from `ovs-vsctl -- --columns=name,ofport list Interface`?

Comment: I did not use this instruction. And I will do it next, but the network in our lab got some trouble, so I cannot make the verification now. Maybe after 3 days I will reply to you.